# MS Graph Java SDK: how to upload a large file to OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to upload file to a OneDrive from my Java application, but i dont understand the flow and dont see any documentation or methods within SKD for file upload.

The only flow i've found is:

```
driveClient.me().drive().root().createUploadSession(uploadProperties).buildRequest().post()
```

But this results in `NPE: source`.

how can i set the content as InputStream ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the *ChunkedUploadProvider*. Here is the official sample code for uploading large files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=java

For me this sample worked for files with size less than 1.9921875 GB. Unfortunately larger files failed with "Upload session failed too many times" error. 
The solution is to get the file size using *File.length()* method:

```
long streamSize = file.length();
```

instead of

```
long streamSize = (long)fileStream.available();
```

as it is shown in the sample.

This happens because *fileStream.available()* returns the available bytes as integer and integer's max value in bytes is ~2GB.

I hope this helps you.